# Cannot change content/child page control with css

Tags: .net, css

I have a master page with a .css file with some instructions. Then i have a content/child page with an image on it that i only want to have on the content page. I want to change properties on that image with css. In my content page i have declared:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
<link href="Styles/imageTest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
...
<asp:Image ImageUrl="" ID="imageDetails" runat="server" /> //this one in the other contentplaceholder.
```

in my .css-file i have:

```
#imageDetails
{
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
```

I can change properties of an image on my master page here in my css-file but not the controls on this very content page.

Why is that? Can one not have a .css for every content page and change the stuff there?

If i put my image on the master page then there is no problem, but i don´t want it there..

Comment: I think I understand you now - when you look at the content page loaded with the master page then everything works - when you look at the content page on it's own there's a problem?

Comment: @web_bod: no not really.. i cannot change the properties on the content page with my css-file that i declared in the content page. i can change my content on my master page but that´s with another .css-file and is not the issue right now.

Comment: why not just use the css file from your master page then?!

Comment: @web_bod: well i don´t want to put the image on the master page, and then, how do i find the control from my master page(css-file) when it´s laying on the content? I just meant that i can change properties on controls that are on the master page.. well i quess i could make i invisible on master page and then call it from inside .cs file when i need it.. but i really wanted to use css.. i will test that..

Comment: @web_bod: i put the image on the master page and changed via a method in master.cs and changed it´s properties from there, i can´t make the css work in master page either.. must be something fundamental i miss, solved the problem but i guess i´ll have to read up on my css. thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the source code you'll probably see something like:

```
<img src="" id="ctl00_MainContent_ctl04_imageDetails" />
```

That's not what your css is looking for, which is why it's not working.

Two solutions:

1 you could swap the id name into a classname

```
.imageDetails  {  width:30px!important;  height:30px!important;  }
```

and try:

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="Images/modellbyggeSim.jpg" ID="imageDetails" class="imageDetails" runat="server"/>
```

2 if you're using .net 4 then you could use the clientmode tag to preserve your id

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="" ID="imageDetails" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"/>
```

[Explaination of clientmode](http://www.shubho.net/2011/01/understanding-clientidmodepredictable.html)

Comment: Tried both methods, no success. What do you mean by source code? not this: <asp:Image ImageUrl="" ID="imageDetails"  runat="server" /> ?

Comment: open the page in a browser and view-source - is the css file loaded into the same page as the image? what's the id of the image in the rendered page (this is what css will be looking for)?

Comment: ok, i found it, it look like this    <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imageDetails" class="test" src="Images/modellbyggeSim.jpg" />,  i tried change my id in my css-file to this one but still the same..

Comment: ok - try: <img id="ContentPlaceHolder1_imageDetails" class="imageDetails test" src="Images/modellbyggeSim.jpg" />, and put in your css .imageDetails  {  width:30px!important;  height:30px!important;  }
 - that has to work!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your two content pages are totally different views that are independent to each other. Therefore you may have to include that css link in the second content page as well to see the magic happen.